# How to get nested floating grouprows in a NSTableView?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

At the moment I have a NSTableView with floating grouprows enabled. What I want to create are nested group rows. By nested I mean the following:

1. Month 1

   - week 1

     - day 1
     - day 2
2. - week 2

     - day 1
     - day 2
3. Month 2

   - week 1

     - day 1
     - day 2
4. - week 2

     - day 1
     - day 2

When you scroll though the view I want is that the Month group view stays at the top of the view until the next month comes along. Meanwhile the week group views stays under the month group view until the next week comes along. The day are normal cells that flow under the month and week group rows.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the floatsGroupRows boolean? Read more about that at the [Apple Developer page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSTableView/floatsGroupRows)